# issue in sending email with custom headers

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I'm having some issues in understanding how to send custom headers with the php `mail()` function.

What's wrong with this code?

```
<?php 
function send_email($name, $lastname, $from, $subject, $message){
    $to = 'to_adress@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'To: ' . $to . 
      '\r\nFrom: ' . $from .
      '\r\nSubject:' . $subject;

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    print 'Email sent';

  }

  send_email('jhon', 'doe', 'from_adress@gmail.com', 'subject', 'message');

 ?>
```

It gives me no php error, and the email does not arrive.

Comment: What does it do, since you're asking? Does it not send an email? Does `mail()` return false? Do you get a PHP error? What happens?

Comment: It gives me no php error. And the email does not arrive

Comment: If you have the option, try a library like phpmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: I'm just making a really simple contact form. I would like to avoid using any other library :)

Comment: if you are trying this on localhost.. check if you have smtp installed..

Comment: I'm running it on my own vps with all these stuff installed

Answer (score 0):

`'\r\n'` is not the same as `"\r\n"`. Try something like this instead:

```
$headers = 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n"
         . 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n"
         . 'Subject: ' . $subject;
```

However you don't need to repeat the `To:` and `Subject:` headers, so just using this should do:

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $from;
```